# writing a line seperated by spaces to a csv file all elements in a different block

Tags: python, csv

I have a tuple in which one element is just a string and the other is a list ('x',['y','z']), I want to output the tuple into a csv file with all of the different elements on the same row, but different blocks.

Here is what I have so far

```
 outputwriter=csv.writer(open('output.csv','wb'), delimiter=' ')
 for tup in in_tup:
    print (tup[0]+' '.join('%s' %x for x in tup[1]))
    outputwriter.writerow(tup[0]+' ' +' '.join('%s' %x for x in tup[1]))
```

when i first print the tuple the output is this

```
xxxx.com 164.44.xx.xx 164.44.xx.xx 164.44.xx.x

...
```

But when I output it to the csv I get all of the text in a signle block "A1" and so on.  I tried a delimiter when I open the csv writer but it doesn't work.  Any thoughts

Comment: You probably want the delimiter to be ','. Excel delimits cell contents in csv's by a comma.

Comment: Danny, that's not his issue even a little bit. Practically it doesn't matter what the delimiter is for a csv document. Tabs, pipes, semicolons, colons, and periods are often used. The python `csv` module deals with all of these just fine.

Comment: @Wilduck His explanation of a block is confusing. It sounds like he is talking about an Excel cell, which Excel only supports commas for a csv.

Comment: Danny, good catch. Sorry for lecturing you, I just assumed the trouble was with the output, not the program he was using to open the output.

Comment: @Danny yea I meant cells like in excel sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
outputwriter = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'), delimiter = ' ')
for tup in in_tup:
    inputList = [tup[0]]
    inputList.extend(tup[1])
    outputwriter.writerow(inputList)
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is correct: You are adding just a single element to each row (which is a long string created by joining all the tuples).

Call `writerow()` with a sequence instead to get multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to join the different elements in your list. The `writerow` method that you are using expects an iterable (like a list or tuple) and will put each element in it's own column, separated by whatever delimiter you specify. If you actually want to use a space as the delimiter the following code should work:

```
outputwriter = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w'), delimiter = ' ')
for tup in in_tup:
    outputwriter.writerow([tup[0], tup[1][0], tup[1][1]])
```

If, however, you're going to be opening this in excel as suggested by Danny, you'll want to change the delimiter to a comma, ','.

Comment: I get what you are doing, however the list part of the tuple varies in length sometimes it could be of size one or one million, how do I get around hardcoding in the [1][x]

Comment: @GregBrown Check my answer to insert the hostname `tup[0]` at the beginning of your list of IPs `tup[1]`